# AngularJs + Best practice to view / update the data - after updation again reload the data in model

Tags: json, angularjs

In my angularjs app, I am little bit confused with respect to standard way of implementation. Please have a look at my code structure and suggest something to make it more effective.

```
var app = angular.module("UserApp", []);

  app.controller('UsersListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/ShowAllUsersList.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.users = data;
    });
  });

  $http.get('/LoggedInUserInfo.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.logged_in_user = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
  }    

  app.controller("LoggedInUserInfoCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.updatePersonalInfo = function() {
      $scope.user_personal_info = {
        username: $scope.logged_in_user.username,
        primary_email: $scope.logged_in_user.primary_email,

        first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
        last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
        secondary_email: $('#secondary_email').val(),
      };

      $http.put('/UpdatePersonalInfo', $scope.user_personal_info).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           alert('Data updated successfully.');
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert('error');
        });
    };

  }]);
```

Now I am not getting the way to reload the data in scope perfectly with out reloading of page. I tried to put onload function but it dnt work. Please suggest something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a service to persist data across controllers and scopes.

Please read the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Also a video : https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am looking for updation of data and then reloading of data using scope by reducing the line of code. Also got the idea of sharing data using function <Controllername>.